# Automatically run a template's subroutines

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a template worksheet as an `.xltm` file ("`TemplateT`").

The goal is to use it to do a series of formattings on the content copied from other files. For example, the user should manually copy the entire **column B** of `Sheet1` in `WorkbookA`, paste it on **column D** in `TemplateT`, and the subroutine should automatically format the range bold (the copied cells are *not* bold in `Sheet1!WorkbookA`).

I tried a very basic example first:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Range("D1:D20").Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Despite using `Workbook_Open()` this isn't working. I have to manually run the code. Preferably, the code should run as soon as `TemplateT` is opened, or when VBA detects new content in the cells (i.e. when content from other workbooks is copied over).

What am I doing wrong? Does this have anything to due with macro safety and Microsoft's protection from malicious code? Or am I simply missing something in my code?

Comment: It's setting the range to bold but when the user manually pastes over Column D they are also pasting the format? Ask them to use Paste Special Values and see if that works. Or use code to assign the values

Comment: You need to implement your code in the sheet's Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range) event, first checking: if not intersect(Target, Range("D1:D20")) is nothing then ....